# Delphi 2009, IdTCPServer1 Access Violation on exit

Tags: delphi, access-violation

I have just started working with Threads use the onexecute event with Delphi 2009, indy IdTCPServer1.  I wrote a very basic application for testing and am getting an access violation on exit.  The application runs fine and does everything I want it to,  but I think that I am leaving "Threads running" on exit.  I have no experience with threads so any help would be appreciated.

Heres my code

```
unit FT_Communicator_pas;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ScktComp, IdContext, IdTCPServer,
  INIFiles, ExtCtrls, ComCtrls, adscnnct,
  DB, adsdata, adsfunc, adstable, Wwdatsrc, Grids, Wwdbigrd, Wwdbgrid,
  IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdCustomTCPServer;


type
  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    IdTCPServer1: TIdTCPServer;
    PgMain: TPageControl;
    TsMain: TTabSheet;
    tsConfig: TTabSheet;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    txtServer: TEdit;
    txtPort: TEdit;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Panel3: TPanel;
    tsLog: TTabSheet;
    mnolog: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button3: TButton;
    procedure IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure IdTCPServer1Disconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
    procedure Logit(const Logstr: String);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;



var
  frmMain: TfrmMain;

implementation
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin


  IdTCPServer1.Active:=FALSE;

  application.Terminate;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdTCPServer1.Active:=true;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PgMain.ActivePage:=tsMain;
  EnableMenuItem( GetSystemMenu( handle, False ),SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND or MF_GRAYED );
end;


procedure TfrmMain.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  mnoLog.lines.Add ('Connected from: ' +  AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP);
end;

procedure TfrmMain.IdTCPServer1Disconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  mnoLog.lines.Add ('Disconnected from: ' +  AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP);
end;

procedure TfrmMain.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  myReadln,mySendln,sqlqry:string;
begin


    sleep(10);

    myReadln:=AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn();
    mnolog.Lines.Add(AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP + '>' + myReadln );
    mySendln:= AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP + ' Sent me ' + myReadln;
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(mySendln);

  try
  except
      on E:Exception do
        begin
            logit('Error occured During execute function ' + #13#10 + e.message);
        end;
  end;

end;

procedure TfrmMain.logit(const logstr:String);
var
  curdate,Curtime:string;
  StrGUID:string;
begin
    StrGUID:=FormatDateTime('YYYYMMDDHHnnsszzz', Now())+'_ ';
    mnolog.lines.add(StrGUID +logstr );
end;

end.
```

Comment: Your try/except block has nothing inside it. Therefore, it can't catch anything. What is its point?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]. I guess that there is a lot more going on, settings in the .dfm file that matter. And presumably the other end of the communication. Don't provide a GUI program. It's a pain to try to get that to run here. Provide a clean [mcve], in the form of a console app.

Comment: I am self taught, so i do not even know how to do a console app but I will give it a go.  Also, for trouble shooting i removed the coded that was in the try except as I read somewhere have a try/except in the Execute event can prevent the control from handling it's own exceptions.  Thanks so much for the reply

Answer (score 2):

Your `TIdTCPServer` event handlers contain unsafe code in them.

`TIdTCPServer` is a multithreaded component, its events are triggered in the context of worker threads.  But you are directly accessing a VCL UI control (`mnoLog`) without synchronizing with the main UI thread. Bad things happen when you do not synchronize, as the VCL is not thread-safe.  You must synchronize properly when accessing the UI from a worker thread.

It is also important to avoid performing a *synchronous* synchronization when deactivating `TIdTCPServer` from the main UI thread, as that will cause a deadlock.  Use an *asynchronous* synchronization instead.

Try something more like the following:

```
procedure TfrmMain.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  Logit('Connected from: ' + AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP);
end;

procedure TfrmMain.IdTCPServer1Disconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  Logit('Disconnected from: ' + AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP);
end;

procedure TfrmMain.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  myReadln, mySendln, peerIP: string;
begin
  myReadln := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn();
  peerIP := AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP;
  Logit(peerIP + '>' + myReadln);
  mySendln := peerIP + ' Sent me ' + myReadln;
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(mySendln);
end;

procedure TfrmMain.IdTCPServer1Exception(AContext: TIdContext; AException: Exception);
begin
  if not (AException is EIdConnClosedGracefully) then
    Logit('Error occured. ' + AException.Message);
end;

procedure TfrmMain.Logit(const Logstr: String);
var
  Str: string;
begin
  Str := Trim(Logstr);
  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      mnolog.Lines.Add(FormatDateTime('YYYYMMDDHHnnsszzz', Now()) + ': ' + Str);
    end
  );
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Remy,  Where does 'EIdConnClosedGracefully' get defined? I am self taught so sorry if this is a simple answer.

Comment: Ok,  I think  i get it. I was accessing the gui objects from a thread.  How do i go about doing this safely.  is there a simple resource / tutorial you can recommend that will help me understand multithreading and how to code with it?  I really appreciate the help.